# How can I limit user login to a certain number of password attempts? Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: login, 15.10, password, user-management

So basically I want to be able to set it to time out after a certain number of password guesses. If this is possible, would this apply to sudo command attempts as well?

Comment: your question is duplicated. see the following link:[link to same question and a it's answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/338588/limit-user-login-attempts-ubuntu-12-10-pam-tally-so-pam-tally2-so)

Comment: Presumably that's what the lock time mentioned in that does?